# How come Oracle reverse key indexes don't cause slow random writes?

Tags: oracle

Oracle's reverse key indexes solve the problem of contention for leaf blocks in the right side of a B-tree index.  But the flip side is that reverse key indexes will cause random writes.  Why is in memory contention worse than disk seeking to do random writes?

edit: Microsoft advises essentially the same thing for SQL Server http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26665

Comment: it's not a disk seeking. initially you write to the buffer cache in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas Kejser answered the question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52601/indexing-a-pk-guid-in-sql-server-2012 but there's a lot of controversy.  It seems up to a point sequential inserts are better and then fan out writes start winning.

Answer (score 3):

The contention stops the execution of the user session, whereas writes (apart from direct path) are asynchronous -- they are carried out by the DBWR process, and the only synchronous disk write is the LGWR writing the redo log entries.

A larger problem might be that you are more likely under some circumstances to need more of the index segment in memory, as "recent" changes are spread over a great many more blocks than on a regular index, so it might be worth keeping an eye on segment statistics, but even if the problem arises it's likely to be of a small magnitude relative to all the other stuff you could be spending your time on.